# Passing list of generic types into method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generic-list

I have a method that dynamically constructs a html table in a MVC project. This table can display a collection of one of four entity types. What I need to do is pass the entity types into the method without coding a method for each type.

This is my method declaration:

```
public static HtmlString Table(int rows, int columns, string[] headers, List<MyInterface> model)
{
    //...
}
```

This is my view and how I call my helper method:

```
@model List<MyModel>

<some html>

@OfficeUiHelper.Table(Model.Count, 5, new string[] { "First Name", "Last Name", "Username", "Company", "Role" }, Model)
```

This is my interface:

```
public interface MyInterface
{
}
```

This is one of my entity types:

```
public partial class MyModel : MyInterface
{
    // Properties
}
```

In conclusion, when I do it like this, I get an error:

> Cannot convert from `"System.Collections.Generic.List<MyModel>"` to
>   `"System.Collections.Generic.List<MyInterface>"`.

Comment: Does the method `Table` really need the full range of options a `List<object>` provides? I.e. adding/removing items or accessing Items by index? Or does it just need "something" it can use in a `foreach`? If it's the latter, maybe you can change `Table` to accept an `IEnumerable<object>`.

Comment: As for *why* you get this exception, please read through [covariance and contravariance (part 2)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance/) and the other parts of that topic by Eric Lippert. Basically, if you have a method `AddLions(List<Animals> animals)` and would be allowed to pass a `List<Giraffe>`, it could get pretty messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an interface that all your four classes implement, then you can pass a list of that interface instead of a list of type `object`. This saves you from many casts.

```
public partial class MyModel : MyInterface
{
    // Properties
}

interface MyInterface {}

public static HtmlString Table(int rows, int columns, string[] headers, List<MyInterface> model)
```

No need for generics at all. Furthermore generics imply that ALL kinds of types that share a condition can be passed, not only a few. So what happens when your user of the method passed a `YourModel`-class instead of `MyMopdel`.

Comment: If all those classes are completely different than this design is broken anyway and he should consider create different methods for every type.

Comment: This works. As per casting, I don't need to because I have custom indexing property in all my models, so I can access their properties by property name.

Comment: You mean by reflection? Not a good idea IMO, at least if you know that you can avoid this quite elegantly and easily.

Comment: Ok, I need to rewind my previous statement, I still get an error very much like the first one, only that it now says that it cannot convert to List<MyInterface> (I edited my question for reference)

Comment: Can you define your model as `@model List<MyModel>`?

Comment: What do you mean? You mean in my view?

Comment: To be honest I´m not familiar with ASP, but I suppose it is the view where you hoöd the reference to the list of your entities.

Comment: Yes, but I already defined it like that in my view while still getting the error.

Comment: Oh, I ment as `List<MyInterface>` instead of `List<MyModel>`.

Comment: Tried it like that but then I get an error that says my View expects a Model of type MyClass.

Comment: For everybody coming across this, I just stayed with standard MVC View scaffolding templates. I will have to manage to  get all same-style elements unto the layouts page. Other solutions are too "against the grain"